# Thread1: Signal SIGABRT in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, watchkit

This iOS Swift code generates the following error at runtime:

> **Thread1:Signal SIGBRT**

Can anyone help me determine the possible cause and solution?

<sup>(*Note: The URL for Amazon.com is hardcoded only for the sake of example.*)</sup>

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {
    //Outlets erstellen
    @IBOutlet var timer: WKInterfaceTimer!
    @IBOutlet var slider: WKInterfaceSlider!
    @IBOutlet var button: WKInterfaceButton!

    //Outlet-Action, bei Änderung des Slider Werts
    @IBAction func slider(_ value: Float) {
        //Button kann genutzt werden
        button.setEnabled(true)
        //Text für den Button wird bestimmt
        let roundedValue = Int(round(value))
        UserDefaults.standard.setValue(roundedValue, forKey: "countdown")
        let text: String = "FIRE (\(roundedValue)s)"
        button.setTitle(text)
    }

    //Outlet-Action, wenn der Button gedrückt wird
    @IBAction func fire(){
        //Timer Farbe wird geändert, um diesen zu sehen
        let swiftColor = UIColor(red: 1, green: 222, blue: 113, alpha: 1)
        timer.setTextColor(swiftColor)
        //Button wird deaktiviert + Button Text nun ...
        button.setTitle("...")
        button.setEnabled(false)
        //Timer  Wert abfragen
        var countdown: Int = (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "countdown")! as! Int)
        //Timer starten
        timer.setDate(NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: TimeInterval(countdown)) as Date)
        timer.start()
        //NSTimer mit 1 Sek Intervall
        var clock = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector: "countdown", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        func countdown() {
            countdown -= 1
            if countdown == 4{
                //HTTP-Request
                var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://amazon.com")!)
                request.httpMethod = "POST"
                let session = URLSession.shared
                session.dataTask(with: request) {data, response, err in
                    print("Entered the completionHandler")
                    }.resume()
                //Timer auschalten
                let schwarz = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
                timer.setTextColor(schwarz)
                //Button in Normalzustand
                button.setTitle("FIRE (0s)")
                button.setEnabled(true)
                //Slider auf Standart
                slider(0)
            }
        }


    }

    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)

    }

    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()
    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
        super.didDeactivate()
    }

}
```

Comment: Make sure no elements on your storyboard are looking for an outlet in your code that doesn't exist

Comment: Where in your code does the error occur?

Comment: Nowhere! It goest to a Thread1 file and shows there.

Comment: @ntoonio there aren`t any outlets wich are not connected

Comment: Did you right click on the elements in the storyboard to see all the connected outlets? (just to be sure we understand each other)

Comment: Attempt to describe the actual technical problem more clearly and succinctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your project. If that doesn't work, recreate any pod files that you may have created while making the project. Also, check if you have multiple outlets or actions for the same object.